#  is an invalid Bash alias

Tags: bash, unicode

On Mac OS X I'm adding an alias to my `.bash_profile`. First I used , but as it is a build command I found  more suitable.

I tried these:

```
alias ='echo "build with fun."'
alias ='echo "build with tools."'
alias ='echo "build with style."'
```

Weirdly,  is not a valid alias, as bash reports:

```
-bash: alias: `': invalid alias name
```

Why is that..?

Comment: Have you tried putting `` in quotes (single or double)?

Comment: Yes, same issue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell wants to quote that name for some reason, and is disallowing it as an alias accordingly. [general.c:legal_alias_name()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;a=blob;f=general.c;h=2d327add634fecb438f419f62f4ffe1835045d7c;hb=HEAD#l339).

This is even though `locale` outputs 'en_US.UTF-8' for all values.

Try a different emoji:

```
~$ alias ='echo oh bother'
~$ 
oh bother
~$ alias ='echo build'
bash: alias: `': invalid alias name
--> 1
```

Why does the shell want to quote that name? My first guess is that  is from Unicode 7.0 while  is from Unicode 6.0, and I used the behavior of `ls` to convince myself of this:

```
~$ touch  
~$ ls -b  
                \360\237\233\240
```

Since I can use  as an alias name on Linux but not macOS, this looked particularly good, since macOS ships with an old version of bash — even though I had installed an up-to-date version using homebrew.

To test this theory, I tried , also from Unicode 6.0:

```
$ alias ,='echo choo choo'
bash: alias: `,': invalid alias name
--> 1
```

So that's not it! And bash on Linux is happy to use all these characters as aliases. (And the behavior of `ls` is a red herring, since it will print  (7.0) as utf-8 but bash on Mac will accept it as an alias name.)

But the alias name function seems to be considering the string as *bytes*, not as characters, and both of those failures end in `0xA0`, which I know is 'non-breaking space' in Latin-1. Without jumping into all the C macro declarations, I bet that character would be suspect.

```
Mac$ alias $'\u00a0'=foo 
bash: alias: ` ': invalid alias name
--> 1
Linux$ alias $'\u00a0'=foo
Linux$ $'\u00a0'
 : command not found
--> 127
```

So apparently, select a character whose UTF-8 encoding does not contain an `A0` byte. But I have no clue why this check is being ignored on my Linux machine.

Comment: Mac is "doing it wrong", an '0xA0' is a perfectly valid continuation byte for UTF-8. It i wrong and incorrect to try to interpret valid UTF-8 as ISO-8859-1. That "check" has no real meaning.

Answer (score 1):

you need back slash `\` to ignore the special meanings

> alias \='echo "build with fun."' 
> alias \='echo "build with
>   tools."' 
> alias \='echo "build with style."'

***test:***

```
$  tes*
test  test_script.sh  test.sh  test.xml
$grep '' .bash_profile
```

> alias \='ls'

Comment: ct@MBA45:code$ alias \='echo "build with fun."' 
ct@MBA45:code$ alias \='echo "build with tools."' 
-bash: alias: `': invalid alias name

Comment: works fine on Sierra 10.12.06.   GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16)
$ alias \='echo "build with fun."'
$  
build with fun.